# why does the host always response `RST` though the server is listening on the port?

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, tcpdump, netstat

I am using `gitlab docker image` to deploy a service, and the web port is `8080` on host. After running the `gitlab`, I can see the port is OK:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
b85d87da48df        genezys/gitlab:7.5.2   "/bin/sh -c 'gitlab-   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes               0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   gitlab_app
```

The `netstat` command also diplays OK:

```
[root@localhost backup]# netstat -nlp | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      12489/docker-proxy
```

But the web browser can't connect the `8080` successfully (http://10.137.20.112:8080/), and the `tcpdump` output likes this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i enp2s0f1 port 8080 -vv
tcpdump: listening on enp2s0f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
02:40:00.808034 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 4031, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    perfls15.americas.hpqcorp.net.53178 > 10.137.20.112.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x17d1 (correct), seq 997417494, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
02:40:00.808141 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.137.20.112.webcache > perfls15.americas.hpqcorp.net.53178: Flags [R.], cksum 0x788a (correct), seq 0, ack 997417495, win 0, length 0
02:40:01.322048 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 4032, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    perfls15.americas.hpqcorp.net.53178 > 10.137.20.112.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x17d1 (correct), seq 997417494, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
02:40:01.322123 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.137.20.112.webcache > perfls15.americas.hpqcorp.net.53178: Flags [R.], cksum 0x788a (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
02:40:01.821289 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 4033, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
......
```

I can't see why the host always responses `RST`, could anyone give some debugging clues?

Comment: What `docker run` command dod you use? Was there a `-p 8080:8080` in the options of that `docker run`?

Comment: @VonC: The run command is "`docker run --detach --name gitlab_app --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2`", no `-p 8080:8080`.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/genezys/docker-gitlab, did you tried it with gitlab:7.8.4 (instead of the older 7.5.2)? `genezys/gitlab:7.8.4`

Comment: @VonC: I remember there are some issues in the newer version, and the `7.5.2` is very stable, so we still use `7.5.2`. IMHO, I don't think this issue is related to version, because it doesn't occur every time. Sometimes after restarting `docker container`, it works OK. But it occurs toady, I want to drill down the root cause.

Comment: OK. Did you tried it with a docker 1.6.1?

Comment: @No. OK, I can try a higher version of `docker`. What confuses me is why the `kernel` responses `RST` though there is a listening port, is there any method to analyze what the `kernel` has done?

Comment: @VonC: It is `RHEL7`, and the kernel version is `Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64`.

Comment: OK. I never ran docker on such an old kernel (3.10 is the minimum, so there could be a side-effect there)

Comment: Have you checked the kernel firewall rules to make sure the port’s not blocked there?

Comment: @alanc: After executing "`service iptables status`" and "`service ip6tables status`" commands, they all show "`Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory) Active: inactive (dead)`", so I think the kernel firewall rules aren't the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Check output of 'iptables -L -n'. If you do not see port 8080 opened in that ouput, you may need to do so

with RHEL7, you need to use firewall-cmd as below

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I have 2 servers. One is OK while the other is not. For the 2 servers. executing "`iptables -L -n`" both output nothing, so I think it is not the root cause. BTW, the OP issue isn't always reproduced, and sometimes work right. So I think if it is related `firewall`, it should always works wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I understood the issue. So it could be related to docker container net namespace. When the issue is present,do you have access to any other services that might be running from the container?

Comment: Thanks for your response! "`access to any other services that might e running from the container`", could you give an example?

Comment: From your docker run command port 2222 is also being forwarded to gitlab container, do you get a response, when you try to telnet to port 2222? Only thing, I can think of is somehow iptables NAT setup is being messed up. Can you share output of 'iptables -L -n -v -t nat' ? there should be some port redirects from docker

Comment: also look at 'docker logs' to see, if gitlab app is having any issues with binding/accepting port requests - when you see the issue